# Vim remap square brackets in Portuguese keyboard layout

Tags: vim

Can you help me to remap my `[` and `]` to another key.
I already put on my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap º [
nnoremap ` ]
```

Here the [mac portuguese keyboard layout](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2841/Portuguese.gif)

On python-mode i should be abble to press `ºº` and this translates to `[[` or `´M` ->
 `]M`.

I want to avoid the extra `alt` key `alt+(` to get `[`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remapping just a single character doesn't affect multiple-character commands (this also comes up with the `<C-W>` command group).

#### A)

The `'langmap'` option seems to be one solution:

```
:set langmap=º[,`]
```

#### B)

Or, you additionally remap all the compound combinations:

```
:nnoremap ºº [[
:nnoremap º` []
" ... etc.
```

#### C)

My personal solution (for German umlaut characters): I've switched my system's keyboard layout to US-English (which is more amenable to programming than the German one), and (since I almost exclusively use Vim to type longer texts) use Vim's *digraphs* to insert special characters.

Comment: I will try to use US-English to programming.