# Can't type {} or @ in Vim editors

Tags: vim, macvim

Im trying to start using VIM once again, but just got into a dead-end. Im using a Portuguese layout keyboard, and I can't type curly brackets or the at symbol inside vim.

Anyone knows what I need to change to have them work normally?

Update:
As Barton points out, I should have provide more complete information, here it goes:

When I type ALT+2 (in my keyboard it's how I type @) i get the 2 exponent symbol.

For curly brackets I usually type ALT+Shift+8 / 9, that usually gives me { and }, in VIM shows a small quote like symbol and the © symbol.

When I run the :abbreviate command I get "No abbreviation found".

Update2:
I've also noticed that on iTerm I can type the symbols in vim mode, just not on VIM GUI's.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but can you type anything else in vim? And can you type `{`, `}`, and `@` outside vim?

Comment: Please describe *what happens* when you type `{`, `}` and `@` ... are the characters not appearing on the screen? Are you seeing different characters? Any error messages? Also, do you have any abbreviations defined? (use `<esc>:abbreviate` to list these). Update your question with the answers.

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen correct, outside VIM I can type those symbols and other that the symbols I've mentioned I didn't find yet other issues. I've updated the question with the behaviour I get when trying to get curly brackets and the at symbol.

Comment: Do you have any evironment variables of the form `$LC_*`? You can view these with the `env` command at your shell. Also `$LANG`?

Comment: Running `env` it get:
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

No $LANG variable though.

Comment: Typically you press `AltGr` to get those symbols, not `Alt`.

Comment: Im on mac, where there's no AltGr, hence the Shift+Alt which is equivalent to AltGr on windows.

Comment: Another troubleshooting question is doe this happen when you run vim with no plugins `vim -u NONE`

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430731/vim-remap-square-brackets-in-portuguese-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered what was causing my problems:

```
set macmeta
```

It wasn't easy to catch this one.

Comment: I tried this and got an error: "E518: Unknown option: macmeta"